# L1B visa interview : Getting hired with different team with Internal Transfer

Tags: working-visas, l1-visa

My friend is planning to move to US. He attended interview with different team in same company and they are planning to file L1B visa.

Question is what should be our answer for "What is your roles and responsibilities / Specialization" in visa interview. Since he is moving to new team he has no knowledge about the product , can we say that im moving the the same team and talk about the roles in team in India , will that be okay is there any way they will find out. How you people handle this situation.

Comment: Has your friend tried asking the team he will be moving to? What does the job description say about what responsibilities/specialisation the role involves?

Comment: Did he check the package he got from the company's lawyer and what it says there?